# Some kind of equine religion?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Short clue.

> This is simply a space filler to satisfy the SE editor. It does not form part of the puzzle.

Comment: I am not personally opposed but I suspect this could go under for being too broad. I am sure there is some answer where it is like WOAH BRILLIANT, but it seems initially to be broad.

Comment: It was meant to be a quickie and it was. Sometimes people take these puzzles too seriously. By the way, "WOAH" was highly relevant -- your subconscious telling you the answer maybe?

Comment: Like it! Pithy.

Comment: @Goinghamateur, I see what you are saying about 'too broad'. However I don't really agree. The fact that there is so little to go on surely indicates that all the required information is contained within a very small space--the title being the main part of that. Anyone who has done a cryptic crossword will recognise the "Some kind of ...?" format and thus know the types of thing to look for. An anagram is very common  sort of cryptic clue. I think my judgement was borne out by the fact that you did in fact get the answer remarkably quickly.

Comment: Response: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23364/relatively-perverted

Comment: P.S.  It's noteworthy that (as I type) opinion is split. The question has 7 upvotes and 7 downvotes. I wonder if this is representative of the members as a whole? There are certainly divergent attitudes to what constitutes a 'good' question and they are generally quite polarised IMO.

Comment: P.P.S just seen the one from AE!

Comment: -1: Unclued anagrams do not make good puzzles.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Horse Cult.

it is an anagram of short clue.