# Relatively perverted?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Longer clue.

> In response to [Some kind of equine religion?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23360/some-kind-of-equine-religion)

Comment: See also: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24851525#24851525

Comment: @Deusovi, your tag edits to multiple questions are changing the authors' intent. If you don't like these questions then fair enough, you can down vote them, but please don't spoil them for other people.

Comment: @AE: At this point these puzzles have become a genre and are no longer enigmatic.

Comment: @Deusovi, you changed all of them, so "at this point" is not a relevant term. If you don't like them then fine - down vote them or ignore them - but please don't break them for other people. It's just unnecessary.

Comment: @AE: Fair enough, sorry about that. What's the point of keeping the enigmatic tag when the anagram tag is there though? (And if you take off the anagram tag, then the puzzle is underclued.)

Comment: @Deusovi, sorry, I may have been a bit too brisk there. Apologies. Ultimately I think the point of the enigmatic tag is for where the puzzle-creator wants it to be 'underclued'. ;)

Comment: @AE: Hm, I've always seen the enigmatic tag as one for "hunt-style" puzzles - multi-step puzzles where you'll know you're on the right track at various points throughout the puzzle. [This](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/a-well-balanced-puzzle-logic-puzzles-in-visual-disguise) is a prime example - no instructions are given, but the puzzle is completely solvable without any leaps of logic. Unclued anagrams are too much of a leap without any confirmation.

Comment: @Deusovi - Cluing an anagram makes it pointless. Most of the fun is in working out that it *is* an anagram. (Certainly for this series anyway.)

Comment: Two different things really when we talk about 'clued' versus 'unclued': 1) Is there a clue that this is an anagram? (not explicitly, although the link to the previous question gives a strong hint) and 2) Is there a clue what the answer is meant to be? (the title). Suggest we take this discussion to meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer

> Uncle Ogler  (or of course ogler uncle)

Reason

> uncle = relative
>  It's rather perverted if your uncle ogles you!

Comment: Grrr. Realised my mistake and found you'd just beaten me!

Comment: Beaten by a matter of seconds. ;)

Comment: I was lucky to get there in time. I was in the middle of typing a long comment when you posted the question and had to react sharpish as soon as I saw it!