# What Britney Spears is famous for

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, anagram

And an even longer clue: tolerating a look at her belly.

> In response to [Some kind of equine religion?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23360) and [Relatively perverted?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23364)

Comment: Although I started this trail and heartily applaud its continuance (never thought I'd use that word!), I think there may be too many options possible with a clue of this length. Can you find a way of narrowing it down?

Comment: She's famous for singing dance pop targeted at high-schoolers.

Comment: @IanMacDonald, if you post that as an answer, I will upvote it.  Seriously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Endure glance on navel?

Reason:

> The answer is an anagram of the clue
>
>  $~~~~~~~$  AND AN EVEN LONGER CLUE $~~=~~$ ENDURE GLANCE ON NAVEL.
>
> To endure is to tolerate, and a "look at the belly" could be a "glance on navel".

I admit I had an anagram generator help me a little (not completely), so apologies if that's considered cheating.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be:

> One Unclad Navel Genre

because

> BS is famous for her unclad navel

?

Or perhaps:

> Nude navel race on glen

because while I don't *remember* a Scottish theme to any BS music videos, I'm happy to say I'm not much of an expert on the topic.